# In Ktor how do I get the sessionId within a get() {}?

Tags: ktor

```kotlin
    install(Sessions) {
        header<MySession>("MY_SESSION", SessionStorageMemory())
    }

     get("/session/increment") {
            val session = call.sessions.get<MySession>() ?: throw AuthorizationException()
            call.sessions.set(session.copy(count = session.count + 1))

// insert code here to get sessionId ?

            call.respondText("Counter is ${session.count}. Refresh to increment.")
        }
```

I've been trying to get it out of the attributes but it seems the framework has made all those data structures private to prevent me from getting the sessionId and have no working solution yet.

```kotlin
                    val attributeKey = call.attributes.allKeys.map{
                        val x = it as AttributeKey<Any>
                        call.attributes.get(x)
                    }
               //     AttributeKey<SessionData>("SessionKey")
```

SessionData is private so I can't get access to data structure that holds sessionId

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by the framework making things private. The framework doesn't do anything like that. You should be able to access sessionId by just writing `session.sessionId`. Or am I missing something?